# Getting npm bundle error react-native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

[image: NPM Bundle Error React Native]

Unable to bundle js scripts for react-native. Metro bundler has suddenly started to fail in showing this error. I removed node_modules and ran `npm i` and still get this error.

Answer (score 2):

You need to delete both ios,android and node module folder. Run the following commands

```
> npm install //to get the node module folder

> react-native upgrade //to get android and ios folder

> react-native link // for linking the libraries

> react-native run ios/android
```

Comment: I will able to fix it by adding util v0.10.0 module. I will also try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can install npm i sha --save and run your project